# Login by ssh , change the remote PS1 and don't quit the remote ssh shell

Tags: ssh, python, shell, remote

I want to change PS1 when i ssh another centos

```
    strshell = 'PS1="remote!"'
    os.system("ssh -i %s -l%s -p%s %s %s"%(SSH_KEY,SSH_USER,SSH_PORT,des,strshell))
```

ssh quit automatically. I want to stay in this shell.How to achieve it.

I just change another way to do this

```
 tin = ' sudo -i ; export PS1="Remote! \W :"; exec /bin/bash -i'
 os.system("ssh  -i%s -l%s -p%s %s -t%s" % (SSH_KEY, SSH_USER, SSH_PORT, des, tin))
```

but i changed my local machine prompt not the remote one. why?
  **os.system is a python function**

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add this to `.profile` file on all your hosts.

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
   PS1="Remote! \W : "
else
   PS1="Local: "
fi
```

Comment: I want remote machine to achive this not my machine.So,I want to know how to make it.

Comment: @michael_stackof You place it on the remote machine.

Comment: @ArcherGodson  No, I can't do this. My aim to link other many remote machines by ssh,there are hundreds of them. I can just change PS1 in my script.